# How to access an element of collection inside the collection?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

So I got this code:

```
List chunks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>(1);
```

And I need to get a child of an inner ArrayList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First fix the declaration part

```
List<List<Block>> chunks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>(1);
```

or even better if you are using Java 7

```
List<List<Block>> chunks = new ArrayList<>(1);
```

And then

```
chunks.get(0).get(0);
```

Will give you the inner element `Block`, assuming you have already added the elements in it.

If no elements added at that place, you'll run into exception.

Comment: It doesn't work, claming ArrayList<Block> is an Object (that has no get()).

Comment: @Adflixit: That's because you have `chunks` declared incorrectly in your code. It should be `List<List<Block>> chunks`, not `List chunks`.

Comment: @Adflixit Added that portion aswell.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<List<Block>> chunks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>(1);
```

creates an empty `ArrayList`, so you can't `get` anything from it.
Note that I changed the type of `chunks`. If you use a raw type (i.e. `List`), `chunks.get()` will return an instance of `Object` type, and you'll have to cast it (unsafely) to `List<Block>` in order to obtain elements from the inner `List`.

First you have to add something to it :

```
chunks.add (new ArrayList<Block>());
```

Then you can get the inner `ArrayList` and `add` an element to it :

```
chunks.get(0).add (new Block());
```

Then you can obtain the inner element via :

```
Block b = chunks.get(0).get(0);
```